# $\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]$

Tags: probability, expectation

Is it possible to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X^2 Y]$, where $X$ and $Y$ are standard normal random variables with a correlation $\rho$?

I can't do it using covariance or a law of iterated expectations, since I can`t find $\mathbb{E}[X^2\mid Y]$...

Comment: Are there any other assumptions on $X$ and $Y$? Are they bivariate normal?

Comment: The following should be made explicit. The question stops short of saying $X,Y$ are JOINTLY normally distributed. It is possible for them to be separately normally distributed and to have correlation $\rho$ with their being jointly normally distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, $E[X^2Y]=E[E[X^2Y\mid Y]] = E[YE[X^2\mid Y]]$.  But now $E[X^2\mid Y]=\operatorname{Var}[X\mid Y]+E[X\mid Y]^2 = (1-\rho^2) + \rho^2 Y^2$  Thus the answer is $E[(1-\rho ^2)Y+\rho Y^3]=0+0=0$

Note that $E[Y^3]=0$ as $Y^3$ and $-Y^3$ have the same distribution (and are absolutely integrable).

If $X$ and $Y$ are not assumed to be jointly normal, there should be an interval (depending on $\rho$ and including $0$) such that you can make $E[X^2Y]$ be anything in that interval.  To see why this can be non-zero you can arrange for $Y$ to be positive when $|X|$ is large and for $Y$ to be negative when $|X|$ is small.

Comment: Can we assume that $Var(X|Y) = 1-\rho^2$ and $E[X|Y] = \rho Y$ here? The question doesn't seem to make the assumption of joint normality.

Comment: I assumed they were jointly normal.  It's fairly obvious there is no single answer otherwise.

Comment: I revised my answer to take both cases into account.